# Strange Behaviour with change properties of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've this code:

```
<table border="1" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td class="pointer" style="padding: 2px;"><input style="margin-left: 2px;" type="checkbox" name="nuovoCheck" id="newCheckId" value="N" /></td>
        <td id="textCheckNuovo" class="pointer" onClick="return selectNew();"><b>New</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with the associated script:

```
function selectNew() {
    if ($('#newCheckId').prop('checked') == false) {
        $('#newCheckId').attr('checked', true)
    }
    else {
        $('#newCheckId').attr('checked', false)
    }
}
```

I don't know why this work just for 1 times:

- I click and the checkbox its checked
- I click another time and the checkbox its uncheked.
- But if click for the third time nothing happens.

I don't understand.

I want this: if the text near the checkbox its clicked then the checkbox have to be checked

Comment: Why not `$('#newCheckId').prop('checked', true)` in `if` and `else` `onClick` should be `onclick` in mark-up

Comment: It works for me in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Probably caused by an older jquery version.

Comment: it's possible, @Alist34 please define vrsion of jquery, firefox, chrome?

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Uhf/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function selectNew() {
            if ($('#newCheckId').prop('checked') == false) {
                $('#newCheckId').prop('checked', true)
            }
            else {
                $('#newCheckId').prop('checked', false)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle going with HTML5 compatibility, the "`label`" tag handles this, ties the text semantically (I.E. it is understood to be linked actually as a label for the checkbox), and works without javascript (for browsers that are HTML5 compliant)

E.g.

```
<table border="1" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td class="pointer" style="padding: 2px;"><input style="margin-left: 2px;" type="checkbox" name="nuovoCheck" id="newCheckId" value="N" /></td>
        <td id="textCheckNuovo" class="pointer"><label for="newCheckId">New</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See this JS fiddle (without javascript) for an example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/RKuhT/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    if ($('#newCheckId').prop('checked') == false) {
        $('#newCheckId').prop('checked', true)
        $('#newCheckId').attr('checked', true)
    }
    else {
        $('#newCheckId').removeAttr('checked')
    }
```